# How can I organize my tables?

Tags: sql-server, schema

My database contains more than 200 tables. When I want to modify or insert a table, I find it difficult to find it among all those tables.

- Is there any way to collect related tables in a folder structure inside my DB? I'd have groups of folders, each one containing tables for a certain part of my application.
- If that's not possible, how can I manage all these tables and make it easy for myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there any way to collect tables related to certain part in a folder inside my DB?? ..so i have group of folders each one contain tables of certain part of my application

The direct answer to that within SSMS would be no.

However, there are two ways you can go about this:

1. **Use schemas** to contain logically connected and functional objects
2. **Use a BroadToSpecific naming convention** to alphabetically group objects (I.e. `Person`, `PersonAddress`, `PersonAddressArchive`, etc.  These will appear alphabetically grouped)